# Win32: How to write multiple buffers into NamedPipe using a single OVERLAPPED operation?

Tags: winapi, named-pipes, overlapped-io

Is there a way to write multiple buffers into NamedPipe using a single OVERLAPPED operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not directly, no.  You would have to copy the buffers into a single contiguous memory block and then write that instead.

Comment: On second thoughts, what's wrong with [`WriteFileGather`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365749(v=vs.85).aspx) ?

Comment: D'oh!  I see the problem; presumably, FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING isn't valid for pipes.  @Martin: note that unless the buffers are quite small, it's probably going to be more efficient to just do multiple operations.  This isn't usually as inconvenient as it sounds, because you'd have had to track the buffers anyway in order to free them once the operation is complete.

Comment: Multiple operations are OK in fact. What's annoying is having multiple completion events. Is it possible to do multiple writes and have only a single completion event?

Comment: @MartinSustrik: in message mode, no. Reads/writes are 1:1.  But in stream mode, I would assume so, just provide a bigger buffer to read into.